# Dart - Require return in anonymous function when type is specified

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there an analyzer option or linter rule in Dart that requires the return in anonymous functions when they have a return type specified? For example, in the `MaterialApp` widget constructor there is a parameter called `onGenerateRoute`. This parameter requires a function or anonymous function that takes in a `RouteSettings` object and returns a `Route` object.

So it should look something like this when it is made:

```
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    return Route();
  },
```

However, I can leave off the return statement without the IDE notifying me that I should be returning a `Route` object:

```
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    //no return statement
  },
```

Is there an analyzer option or linter rule that will make the IDE notify me?

Comment: As of now, I don't think so. But they are working on non-nullable types for Dart, so this soon will not compile

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thats good to hear. I do not like the current state of Dart's type system. It feels like the bastard child of JavaScript and Kotlin. Though it is much better than it was before.